# Change A Password

Tags: windows-8, windows-domain

I have a non-domain machine that I use with our company's domain resources over vpn regularly.  I switched to Windows 8 (fresh install), and the "Change a password" option went away from the Ctrl-Alt-Del window.

Can't seem to google anything about this subject, or find a way to access that password change dialog.

I tried running the .reg file from http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63014-ctrl-alt-del-screen-add-remove-change-password.html with no luck.  I also tried to Disable "Remove Change Password" via gpedit.msc.

I could do it from my domain laptop, but I like to do it on this machine because it updates all my saved copies of those credentials.

My local account is tied to my hotmail account if that matters.

Updates: 
Administrator account.  I apologize for stating this was an upgrade, it was a fresh install to a diff't drive.  64-bit Pro install.

**Bounty's almost up** If someone can just confirm that the Change A Password... should or should not be present on a non-domain, Live tied, Win8 install, I'll be satisfied that I can or cannot expect to fix it.

Comment: What did you upgrade the system from?  What sort of account is it "user" or "administrator" more information is needed.

Comment: **It should be present.** This was only downvoted once. The reasons still stand for my original downvote.  You sure this isn't the case your local account was converted to a Microsoft Account thus changing your password through Windows obsolete?

Comment: I'm not sure, hence my question. I could not find any thing that stated that the Change A Password tool is not available in that case.  I'm not sure what this site is for, if not getting knowledge from people with more experience than yourself.  If I could find the answer on google, I wouldn't have asked.  I don't necessarily care about your downvote, but I disagree with your reasoning.

Comment: This website is for exactly that purpose. As I explained I required more information, for example, I also realized you converted the local account to a Microsoft Account which is the reason the `Change a Password` option was removed.

Comment: I did the MS account at install.  Wish they explained the ramifications then.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How the Ctrl+Alt+Delete screen looks to a local account

[image]

### How the Ctrl+Alt+Delete screen looks to a Live account

[image]

I'm assuming the reason for this has to do the the winlogon process that handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and that the whole client-server communication with Microsofts services shouldn't be initiated through it.

Comment: So lame :)  Thank you for the clarity of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Microsoft account, change your password on their site. Easiest way is through Hotmail.com or Outlook.com, and going through the Preferences.

For a local account, you can also try running `control userpasswords`, and changing the password from there

**EDIT**: Based on your comments, if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> doesn't work, you can try typing `NET USER username password /DOMAIN`. A full command includes:

`NET USER [username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]`

A reference page [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/net-user-command.htm) explains what the options are. I do not know of a way to get the actual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> prompt back though, for changing a password

Comment: I'm trying to change a domain password over VPN, from my local account.  On Win7, I could ctrl-alt-del and 'Change A Password...'.  That option is not present on my Win8 install.

Comment: @Thomas See updated answer; hopefully that helps

Comment: How do I specify an arbitrary domain to use? Tried: net user domain\user * /DOMAIN.  Seems /DOMAIN means 'use current domain' but this machine isn't on the domain.

Comment: Try using the full Username (eg `DOMAINNAME\username`). Does that work?

Comment: Nope, see edit of my previous comment.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right... If your computer is not part of the domain when it connects, it won't change it there. I guess the only other option right now is to keep using your domain-controlled laptop. I would guess it's by design the Microsoft did this, for security

Comment: If you're connected to the domain (via VPN) does the option appear? Have you tried it when disconnected (rather than not logged in - ie unplugged from internet)?

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows 8 , Press the Windows Key + R and try the following : **netplwiz**

Answer (score -1):

It sounds too obvious, but I will have to suggest going to the PC Settings (WinKey +i): Users, and Change Password.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I'm not logged into the domain, so my domain user isn't a User of this machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try logging on to a Windows 2003 server using RDP - it should complain that your password has expired and allow you to enter a new one.

Comment: This doesn't solve the author's problem.  He might not have a Windows 2003 license. **The reasont that option was removed is by design.**

Comment: True, it doesn't solve his problem if he doesn't have a Windows 2003 server handy, but I had the same issue and it was the only workaround I could find.

Comment: And of course, he'd have to wait for his password to expire before he could change it!

Comment: His account isn't **NEVER** going to expire since its not a domain account.

Comment: I'd assumed it was his domain account password he was trying to change.

Comment: Can you please read the question. He clearly says that he isn't using a domain account. Did you even read the accepted answer?  His problem was caused by the fact he connected a Microsoft Account to his local account, and since you change the password to your Microsoft Account through a browser, the option to change the password through windows is removed.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, Phil, but Ramhound is correct. My issue isn't with trying to change my domain account's password in general, but wanting to change it from my Win8 account specifically - thus getting all my saved credentials updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - I'd realised I hadn't answered what you were trying to achieve, but a different issue arising from Microsoft removing the Change Password option - no obvious way to change a domain account from Windows 8 when using a live account on a machine that's not a domain member.